# Random jquery ajax error readyState=0

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax

I have a web application that uses jQuery ajax to get some data. In this site I also have a Logger that reports to me when an error happens.

Very frequently I get this error on ajax calls:

> {"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"}

The problem is that this error is randomly and I'm not able to reproduce it. I get this for all ajax scripts. The request is made on same origin and at the server I've defined `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"`.

All browsers get this error:

- Safari 9
- Chrome
- Internet explore 11
- etc...

The jQuery ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'MyUrl',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        data: {dataVars},
        error: function(response, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            log.error( 'StringError: ' + ajaxOptions + '\n\nthrownError: ' + JSON.stringify(thrownError) + '\n\nResponse: ' + JSON.stringify(response));

        },
        success: function(res){


        }
    });
```

The request is performed to a servlet. What could be the problem?

Comment: did you try to debug the request in the server? check if you managed to get to the server? what status code do you get?

Comment: I have this same issue, can't reproduce it

Answer (score 2):

From [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_onreadystatechange.asp):

```
readyState=0
```

Means that the request isn't sent. (your broswer isn't connected to the targeted server).

It's mean that **the socket is not opened** : no TCP handshake, so the targeted URL is just not reached...

So check the validity of `myUrl` (is it a good domain? no cross-origin), and also connectivity of the client (proxy? if `myUrl` is secured / use an other port, maybe it is just not opened...)

I think the issue might be on server side, if it is random. but especially for `myUrl`, if you can get the web page anyway...

But the error is strange, if it comes from the same server!

Anyway, I think it is because the connection between your client and the targeted server is unstable, so maybe you can try to inscrease the timeout of the request, or retry it on error (example with recursive loop):

```
var remainingRetry = 3; //or something else
function handleRequest()
{
    $.ajax({
        url: 'MyUrl',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        data: {dataVars},
        error: function(response, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            if (remainingRetry)
            {
                 remainingRetry--;
                 setTimeout(handleRequest, 1000); //timeout between two tries
            }

            else log.error( 'StringError: ' + ajaxOptions + '\n\nthrownError: ' + JSON.stringify(thrownError) + '\n\nResponse: ' + JSON.stringify(response));

        },
        success: function(res){


        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I've Apache that handle the requests with a proxy pass from port 443 to 8080 where is listening JBOSS. The problem is that the "MyUrl" is relative and if it was wrong the problem couldn't not be randomly... How the connection can be unstable?

Comment: @AndreaCatania do you get this webpage by the proxy? If not, the problem might be the proxy itself...

Comment: And if you use an HTTP tunnel, so... Are your SSL certificate accepted by your browser?

Comment: Yes, both web page and the ajax request go through apache proxypass. And ssl certificate is accepted correctly. If the problem is ProxyPass why this happen randomly?

Comment: Did you try an other proxy program, like nginx? i think because proxy is just an external apache module, it may be instable...

Comment: I cannot install nginx on the server and the host says that all is ok with apache, Now I don't know how to proced...

Comment: I've no access to this, The main panel is cpanel.. I've noticed this error comes mostly with safari 9 browser

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue before and in my case the problem was

that other js function redirecting to another page before my first request has a chance to complete which is practically canceling or killing my request

some thing like

```
    function redirectToAnotherPageFn () {
          window.location = "/otherpage.html"; 
    };
```

Comment: To wait for Ajax request to finish, add to $.ajax() call parameter `async: false`.